# Where the control will go LDPI or Mdpi

Tags: android

I want to test for [Moto](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_razr_xt910-4273.php) razr

In which my control will go, ldpi or mdpi or Hdpi? Please see specification for detail of the device. There is some UI issue so I want to know that.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on your device's density(dpi).

```
Ldpi   -  120dpi and above
Mdpi   -  160dpi and above
Hdpi   -  240dpi and above
XHdpi  -  320dpi and above
```

As [Moto Razr](http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_razr_xt910-4273.php) having *256dp* so it will use the resource from `Hdpi`.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#range

Comment: do you know what the device dencity of Moto razr http://www.gsmarena.com/motorola_razr_xt910-4273.php   ?

Answer (score 0):

Motorola RAZR XT910 is ~256 dpi screen and most likely that it looks for **HDPI** Resource before MDPI.